# PyTorch Calculate covariance matrix using weighted squared difference kernel

Tags: pytorch, tensor

So I have this function [image]

p is the number of features in vector x and i is the ith feature and phi is the coefficient associated with the feature. I'm trying to output a covariance matrix using this kernel. So for example let's say have a square tensor A

```
A = torch.Tensor([[1 , 1]. [0, 1]])
print(custom_kernel(A))
```

should output [[0,-1],[-1,0]] and we'll assume phi is just a 1 vector for this example. How do I implement this?

Comment: Can you define `x'`?

Comment: @ivan x is each column in A. So the rows in A will be a datapoint and x_i is feature i of row data point x

Comment: Yes, but what is `x'_i`?

Comment: a scalar value inside of a vector

Comment: Ok, but what is the definition of `x'_i`? My question is: where does it come from? What is `x'_i` *wrt.* `x_i`??